# How find a given point is with in given distance to a route get from google map direction service

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, google, route, direction

I have created a route with start point, end point and the optional stops points.
I have to check if the given point is away with in a given distance from the route.
I have to match the given points others than the saved points in my DB.
I have saved route's start, end and stops (optional) in the db.

The route is created from google map direction service.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  and edit your question to include what you have tried so far and what, specifically, you are having problems with.